# Mechanism to alternate between two lifting ends

Tags: mechanisms

I'm thinking of what mechanical mechanism can be used to alternate between two different lifting heads, an adhesive and a non-adhesive side, attached to an arm, so that either head comes forward depending on the position of the arm. E.g. moving it down brings one forward, and moving it back up brings the other one forward. I have explained in detail in attached diagram.

[image]

Comment: Two cam and followers would be simple and allow you to set the timing, distance and velocity profiles you require. One would drive the arm and fixed gripper. The other would drive the moving gripper.

Comment: People often use vacuum to to this kind of thing. Try searching on "vacuum end effector".

Comment: There's a wide range of solutions differing in price, robustness and complexity - from very simple, cheap, rather fault-prone and capable of lifting only selected, light objects, to very expensive industrial machinery that never fails. picking and holding firmly heavy masses at superior precision and handling a range of objects. What is your application? A common driver pin of a cheapo electromagnetic linear actuator to push your object away from the adhesive would be probably the simplest... and least robust.